# MySQL - increment values in JSON array

Tags: mysql, arrays, mysql-json

I have a MySQL table which stores user_id and product_ids, where product_ids column stores a JSON array which contains multiple product IDs in the array

| user_id | product_ids |
| --- | --- |
| 102 | [1,58,98,63,45,42,112,115] |
| 54 | [58,63,96,45,28,47,215] |

This table contains thousands of rows. I need a query to increment all the product Ids stored in product_ids column by 1127. So my desired output will be as below:

| user_id | product_ids |
| --- | --- |
| 102 | [1128,1185,1225,1190,1172,1169,1239,1242] |
| 54 | [1185,1190,1223,1172,1155,1174,1342] |

I could anyways write a script which could iterate through each row, select product_ids from JSON column, increment product_ids manually, and then update it back for the current row, but it will be a very time consuming job.

I was wondering if this can be done for all rows with a single query.

Note: This is just a one time activity for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should really normalise your data and have a `user_products` table; then this task would be trivial.

Assuming you're using MySQL 8, you can do this with [`JSON_TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table) and [`JSON_ARRAYAGG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg):

```sql
UPDATE data
JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, JSON_ARRAYAGG(pid+1127) AS product_ids
  FROM data
  JOIN JSON_TABLE(data.product_ids,
                  '$[*]' COLUMNS(
                    pid INT PATH '$'
                    )
                 ) jt
  GROUP BY user_id
) ud ON ud.user_id = data.user_id
SET data.product_ids = ud.product_ids
;
SELECT *
FROM data
```

Output:

```
user_id product_ids
102     [1128, 1185, 1225, 1190, 1172, 1169, 1239, 1242]
54      [1185, 1190, 1223, 1172, 1155, 1174, 1342]
```

Demo on [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7soJZGQaqwEwZepv3w4JN1/0)